# How can i get Vertical Scrollbar for GWT CellTable

Tags: gwt, gwt2

I need a Scroll bar for GWT CellTable. The following is my ui.xml,

```
<gwt:SplitLayoutPanel>
  <gwt:west size="200">
    <gwt:VerticalPanel>
     <gwt:HTMLPanel>
         <table>
            <tr>
               <td>
                  <gwt:Label>xxxx</gwt:Label>
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>
                 **Here i need a CellTable with Vertical Scrollbar**
               </td>
            </tr>
         </table>
     </gwt:HTMLPanel>
  </gwt:VerticalPanel>
</gwt:west>
<gwt:center>
   <gwt:VerticalPanel />
</gwt:center>
</gwt:SplitLayoutPanel>
```

I tried with ScrollPanel --> VerticalPanel --> CellTable. But i'm not getting ScrollBar. Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance,
Gnik

Comment: Does you scroll panel have a fixed size? (a size forced by itself or given by its container). Because if it's not restricted it will be the same size of its content and no scroll will work (I'm almost sure)

Comment: I set ScrollPanel height="100%" and width="100%". as well as for the VerticalPanel. cellTable.setSize("100%", "100%"); Is it correct or not?

Comment: I think the celltable using 100% is exactly fitted into the scroll panel. Try (for test purposes only) setting "800px" to the celltable to see if scroll bars appear :)

Answer (score 4):

What's the point in using of the VerticalPanel in this situation? Replace it by the [ScrollPanel](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.4/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/ScrollPanel.html) in your UiBinder xml-file. Set the *width* and the *height* in pixels for this ScrollPanel(this is very important!) and put in it your CellTable:

```
<g:ScroollPanel pixelSize="200, 400">
   <c:CellTable ui:field="myCellList" />
</g:ScroollPanel>
```

`200` - the width of panel in pixels, `400` - height.

At that the size of the CellTable list must necessarily larger than the size of ScrollPanel. Otherwise, a scroll does not appear.

Or set the *width* in `100%` if you need a vertical scrolling:

```
<g:ScrollPanel  width="100%" height ="400px">
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Gwt 2.4, then replacing the CellTable Object with a DataGrid Object will give you the needed result with no need for a Scrollapanel.
You can see the difference between the celltable and the datagrid in the gwt Showcase (under cell widgets).

Answer (score 0):

The below code worked for me -

```
        <g:HTMLPanel>
    <g:VerticalPanel>
    <g:TabLayoutPanel barHeight="2" barUnit="EM" width="790px"
            height="500px">
            <g:tab>
                <g:header>Sample</g:header>
                <g:DockLayoutPanel>
                    <g:center>
                        <g:ScrollPanel>
                            <p1:CellTable ui:field="cellSampleTable" />
                        </g:ScrollPanel>                            
                    </g:center>                     
                </g:DockLayoutPanel>
            </g:tab>
            </g:TabLayoutPanel>
    </g:VerticalPanel>
</g:HTMLPanel>
```